# Fallback to Virtual Currency or Give Free Items via FB Credits?

Tags: facebook, payment, facebook-canvas, facebook-credits, x-facebook-platform

Is there a way to charge "0" Facebook Credits for a purchase (eg give it away for free to teach users how to use the credits buttons)?

We want to seed our users with items at checkpoints in gameplay but at the same time teach them that they can purchase more with FB credits. We're using FB credits as our currency (with minimal abstraction to our virtual currency as necessary for legacy users and multi-platform users).

Setting the price to "0" credits is returning an error.

Another use case is where our users have in-game credits for half of the value of an item but need to top off for the rest of it. So if they have 3 in-game credits and the item is 6 we'd charge 3 in-game and 3 fb-credits. But we want to make this all one step rather than buying 3 in-game credits and then spending them on the item. Easy enough to set the price with FB credits.. unless that ends up being 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just built my own wrapper around it to ping my server first to try to purchase with virtual currency and then fall back to FB credits if they don't have enough VC to complete the purchase.